# Neo4j browser won't execute query, just clears the query bar

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-desktop

Using the neo4j desktop app and it has suddenly started to clear out the query I wrote,without executing it, when I either hit the run button or hit cntrl-enter.  I have restarted my pc and this didn't help.  Any ideas what might be going on?

I tried to execute MATCH(m:Movie) return m limit 1 (or any query).  I expected it to return the results for the first movie it found but instead it just clears out the query and does nothing else.

Comment: Do you have the most recent version of the software? Is your database running? Has the database table been populated with the `movie` data?

Comment: Were you using a grass file to change the styles? I had this problem when there was an error in the grass file.

Comment: Yes, current version yes database running and populated.  Weirdly it is working today, though wouldn't for hours yesterday.  I guess I'll chalk it up to system gremlins for now and hope it doesn't happen again. Thanks!